# How to replace blank (null ) values with 0 for all records?

Tags: sql, ms-access, null

MS Access: How to replace blank (null ) values with 0 for all records?

I guess it has to be done using SQL. I can use Find and Replace to replace 0 with blank, but not the other way around (won't "find" a blank, even if I enter [Ctrl-Spacebar] which inserts a space.

So I guess I need to do SQL where I find null values for MyField, then replace all of them with 0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to the query designer window, switch to SQL mode, and try this:

```
Update Table Set MyField = 0
Where MyField Is Null;
```

Comment: The first answer is also correct and would have enabled me to get it, but this one has the added benefit of Access-specific instructions that made it go a little faster.

THANKS to all of you for your help, and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 13):

If you're trying to do this with a query, then here is your answer:

> <s>SELECT ISNULL([field], 0) FROM [table]</s>

**Edit**

ISNULL function was used incorrectly  - this modified version uses IIF

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL([field]), 0, [field]) FROM [table]
```

If you want to replace the actual values in the table, then you'll need to do it this way:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [FIELD] = 0 WHERE [FIELD] IS NULL
```

Comment: ISNULL in the presented form does not exist in MS Access SQL

Comment: @Juliusz Correct. The 2nd line, using the `WHERE [FIELD] IS NULL` is the correct usage in MS Access SQL, whether selecting or updating.

Answer (score 5):

without  'where's and 'if's ...

```
Update Table Set MyField = Nz(MyField,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table SET column=0 WHERE column IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE YourTable SET MyField = 0 WHERE MyField IS NULL
```

works in most SQL dialects. I don't use Access, but that should get you started.

Comment: Duplicate answer... but I saw it came in at the exact same date/time as mopoke's....

Answer (score 3):

Better solution is to use NZ (null to zero) function during generating table => NZ([ColumnName])
It comes 0 where is "null" in ColumnName.

Comment: +1 !your answer solves the problem for queries not tables. Additionally, to "clean" a table, you need to create an update query and set the column values like `MyField: NZ(MyField,0)` RUN! Works for Access2013

Answer (score 2):

The following Query also works and you won't need an update query if that's what you'd prefer:

```
IIF(Column Is Null,0,Column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using find and replace will work if you type "null" in the find and put a zero in the replace...you will be warned that this cannot be undone.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the SQL statement above to be more generic. Using wildcards is never a bad idea when it comes to mass population to avoid nulls.

Try this:

```
Update Table Set * = 0 Where * Is Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, and I ended up finding the simplest solution which works for my needs. In the table properties, I set the default value to 0 for the fields that I don't want to show nulls.  Super easy.

Comment: But that will not handle the existing values. It only applies to values that will be added after the change.

Answer (score 0):

I used a two step process to change rows with "blank" values to "Null" values as place holders.

```
UPDATE [TableName] SET [TableName].[ColumnName] = "0"
WHERE ((([TableName].[ColumnName])=""));

UPDATE [TableName] SET [TableName].[ColumnName] = "Null"
WHERE ((([TableName].[ColumnName])="0"));
```