# SQL IIF Isnull and Update set = 0

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

My good reference is [How to replace blank (null ) values with 0 for all records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977133/how-to-replace-blank-null-values-with-0-for-all-records)

**Goal** : I have blank query output. [Image0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iLoe.jpg) I hope to print out 0 instead.

**Problem**: When I tried `IIF Isnull`, I get a prompt message box to enter the parameter value, which I do not want to see.  [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oVaV.jpg)

```
PARAMETERS [BeginDate] DateTime, [EndDate] DateTime;
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold, IIF(ISNULL([SumOfDollarsSold]), 0, [SumOfDollarsSold])
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]) AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo)="M"));
```

Here is the my query looks after running the SQL: [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLlyz.jpg)

Then I tried `UPDATE`

```
PARAMETERS [BeginDate] DateTime, [EndDate] DateTime;
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold
UPDATE [dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold] SET [SumOfDollarsSold] = 0
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]) AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo)="M")) AND [SumOfDollarsSold] IS NULL;
```

It gives me `The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.` error message: [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnWFl.jpg)

Any advice regarding any of the methods I used would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PARAMETERS [BeginDate] DateTime, [EndDate] DateTime;
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold)),0,Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold)) AS SumOfDollarsSold
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]) AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo)="M"))
```

Your query at execution time doesn't know what the column `SumOfDollarsSold` is.  So you would either have to make that a `subquery` and test for a value or you can use the actual aggregation function in your `IIf` statement.

Or perhaps a better thing for display purposes would be the `FORMAT()` function but note then that the number would actually be a string.  I don't remember access's implementation too well but it might be something like:

```
PARAMETERS [BeginDate] DateTime, [EndDate] DateTime;
SELECT FORMAT(Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold)),0) AS SumOfDollarsSold
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]) AND ((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.CustomerNo)="M"))
```

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-Property-Number-and-Currency-Data-Types-ca77795e-b40d-4abb-b42f-daa0bb709620?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thank you! It does make a lot of sense! Will accept your answer in 54 seconds.